# Vagrant - berks error when attempting vagrant up

Tags: macos, vagrant, chef-infra, osx-elcapitan, berkshelf

I'm trying to vagrant up a custom box in my local Mac machine. Because of an issue with VirtualBox's version, I had to format and reinstall OSx. I've installed Chef DK, Vagrant and installed the berkshelf plugin. When I try to vagrant up, I get the following error:

```
 Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/util/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/cdelgado/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-5.1.1/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/helpers.rb:62:in `berks'
    from /Users/cdelgado/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-5.1.1/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/check.rb:33:in `berkshelf_version_check!'
    from /Users/cdelgado/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-5.1.1/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/check.rb:16:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.0/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/logging-2.1.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:450:in `call'
```

My current setup is:

```
Vagrant Version 1.9.0
Chef Development Kit Version: 1.0.3
chef-client version: 12.16.42
delivery version: master (83358fb62c0f711c70ad5a81030a6cae4017f103)
berks version: 5.2.0
kitchen version: 1.13.2

vagrant-berkshelf (5.1.1)
vagrant-omnibus (1.5.0)
vagrant-share (1.1.6)
```

When I disable berkshelf in the recipe it runs, but obviously the dependencies don't work.

If I downgrade the berkshelf plugin to 5.0.0 I get a different error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
/Users/cdelgado/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-5.0.0/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/helpers.rb:62:in `berks': uninitialized constant VagrantPlugins::Berkshelf::Helpers::Bundler (NameError)
    from /Users/cdelgado/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-5.0.0/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/check.rb:33:in `berkshelf_version_check!'
    from /Users/cdelgado/.vagrant.d/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-5.0.0/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/check.rb:16:in `call'
```

I've been googling for days now with no luck, please help.

Comment: Try `vagrant plugin install bundler`?

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives a different error: `Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

Comment: You probably need to remove it from the plugin manifest, you want to leave the gem installed but not try to load it as a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

After many days googling with a colleague, we compared our versions and narrowed the problem down to the Vagrant version. I was running 1.9.0 and he was running 1.8.4. Since the same recipe did work on his machine, I downgraded Vagrant to his version and voilá, it worked. We still don't know what's the exact difference and why does this problem occur, but this will do for now.

I hope this helps whoever stumbles into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade or install your vagrant-share plugin.
Run this command:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-share --plugin-version 1.1.8
```

Adapt the version based on the newest or desired one.

If it doesn't work for you (worked for me), there is an issue on GitHub about this
[here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8520).